# how to close popup window from asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, popup

I want to close some html popup windows. I have static site, which creates popup windows. These windows have a submit button, which sends a POST request to asp mvc app. This app works well and return View() (Index page with message "Ok". And Button "Close").

When I click on Close button- nothing happens.

My code:

```
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="window.parent.jQuery('#btn, #m_window').hide('slow');">Close</button> 

   
<!--   <button type="button" id="btnFoo" onclick="$("#btnFoo, #m_frame").live("click", function(){
    $("#mistake").remove();
});  ">Close form </button>
   -->
</body>
```

m_frame- frame of popup window.
mistake- div of popup window.

Please, tell me how to close this popup window?

`window.close()` doesn't work.

P.S. at js script (when popup creates) I write:

```
$("#btn",#m_window").live("click",function(){
var p = parent;
 var win = p.document.getElementById('mistake');
 win.parentNode.removeChild(win);
});
```

But it doesn't works too.

Comment: `$('#btn, #m_window').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#displayinmodal").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $("#displayinmodal").dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="displayinmodal">
    Popup demo
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
window.close();
```